# Is it possibly to bind IDictionary using lambdas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

My answer is can I anyhow bind an IDictionary property using lambda expressions as it done in MVC 2 for simple properties?

I know how to bind IDictionary using old MVC notation via string property paths. But all the rest of model properties throughout all application operate using new MVC 2 approach, via lambda expressions. And therefore I extremely would not like apply old manner of model binding.

I saw also an article [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) posted by Phil Haack in his blog. But in that article Phil shows how to do binding using lambdas just for Lists, not for Dicrionaries. I tried to do similar with Dictionary typed properties, but DefaultModelBinder does not recognize them.

Example:

binding is:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DictionaryProperty[key].Title)%>
```

rendered html is:

```
<input id="DictionaryProperty_one__Title" name="DictionaryProperty[one].Title" type="text" value="" />
```

I would be appeciated for any helpful advices.

UPD: A index for dictionary property mentioned above was specified, of course:

view:

```
<%= Html.Hidden("DictionaryProperty.index",key)%>
```

rendered html:

```
<input id="DictionaryProperty_index" name="DictionaryProperty.index" type="hidden" value="one" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like OrderedDictionary class for your DictionaryProperty

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx